# How to Decrypt data in Flex using RSA?

Tags: apache-flex

I have encrypted my data using RSA in Asp.net. Now i need to use the data in flex by decrypting it. Could any one guide me how to decrypt the data in Flex which was encrypted in .Net using RSA.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good library for actionscript encryption/decryption - [as3crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/). It should be exactly what you need.